# Weibel's proof of the fact that "A left derived functor is a homological delta-functor"

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

The theorem 2.4.6 of Weibel's homological algebra is about the fact that an additive functor's
left derived functors form a (not dealing with the universality yet) homological delta-functor.
And most part of the proof is for showing the naturality of the connecting maps. But I thought,
reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma, that the whole process could be settled
by the snake lemma guaranteeing even the naturality of the connecting map. Is my thought wrong
and such a complicated argument inevitable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how do you prove the snake lemma, with the naturality you wish to use?

Comment: The *Principle of Conservation of the Difficulty* applies here

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood Weibel's proof. The most part of the proof is **NOT** showing the naturality of connecting maps, but rather constructing a particular chain map $F:P\to Q$ that lifts $f:A\to B$ and fits in long exact sequences; also noting that this chain map $F$ has nothing to do with the right exact functor $F$ as in $L_*F$ which is really confusing. You may think of it as the natuality of Horseshoe lemma.

Comment: @LucelliaKassel 
Oh crap you are completely right. It was so dumb of me. To apply the naturality of 
snake lemma I have to construct F, proving the naturality of Horshoe lemma. Thank
you so much!